# Dell UP2715k 5k vs SW2700pt

Tags: graphics-card

I am little bit confused between the Dell UP2715k 5k Monitor and BenQ SW2700pt 2k monitor.
I am a photographer and i need to produce the best color for my work.
I'm just a little bit concerned about the Dell 5k if it will work on my system plus it must be connected through two Display ports.
System: 
i7 4790K Windows 10 64 bit
16Gb RAM
GEFROCE GTX 960 4gb

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Answer (score 0):

IF the question is whether the monitor will work on your system then the answer is YES.

Your system is powerful enough to be able to work with 5k applications. Both your processor and your video card will have no problem rendering or editing photos in 5k.

Comment: That's good to hear but which one your prefer for photography and design work?

Comment: @AhmedKhaled I do not know so much about this subject. There are websites that make reviews and tests of various monitors.